# missing function descriptions (IDE)

Tags: c++, function, intellisense

i am currently learning c++ for uni.
Currently using visual studio code (primarily), visual studio enterprise and visual studio community.

Im wondering if theres any way to make a description of functions show up when im typing them. When i write in javascript I always get a description, but not c++ (see pic)

[image]

as you can see when im writing in javascript i get a decent description of what the function does when i start to write it out, can i get that for c++ too somehow?
if not, is there a better way than googling each individual function to figure out what they do?
thanks!

Comment: There is no software called “visual studio code/community/enterprise”. “Visual Studio Code” and “Visual Studio” are different pieces of software, and the latter has a Community edition and an Enterprise edition. Which of these three distinct pieces of software are you using? (It looks like VS Code but I’m not sure …).

Comment: Your java library is commented. The standard library has no comments. You will have to [use the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) if you want information about the likes of std::vector.

Comment: @KonradRudolph edited my question for clarity, thanks. I used visual studio code for the picture, however i usually use visual studio enterprise for c++. the descriptions popups are identical when coding in visual studio code and visual studio enterprise or community

Comment: The comments are identical because they are not part of Visual Studio. They are comments in the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your java library is commented. The standard library has no comments. You will have to [use the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) if you want information about the likes of std::vector

The comments are not part of visual studio, they are in the source code you are referencing. You can see this for yourself Put this little program in editor.

```
//thus there is a comment
struct mystruct {};

int main()
{
    mys //<< start typing this here
}
```

`mys` should show in the selections. When you get to seeing `mystruct` in the selector, you will also see 'thus there is a comment` in the tool tip.